How to use the Chinese characters ‘卧’ and ‘躺’ accurately?
The Chinese characters ‘躺’ and ‘卧’ are synonyms. When I looked up the example sentences in the dictionary, I found that in real life people use the Chinese character ‘躺’ , but rarely ‘卧’. However, the Chinese character ‘卧’ means to lie down, for example: ‘奶奶卧病在床.’ Here it means that grandma is lying in bed. Why do you use the Chinese character ‘卧’, and is there another meaning?

卧和躺的区别
(Whoops, the numbering went wrong! Should be 1 to 5)

卧和躺都是描述身体位置的动词，

卧 and 躺 are both verbs which describe the position of the body,
它们之间有一些细微的差别。
(but) there are some subtle differences between them.
卧通常指的是身体平躺在地上或床上，
卧 usually refers to the body lying flat on the ground or on a bed,
是一种比较放松的姿势。
(which) is a relatively relaxed posture.

躺则更多指身体平放在平面上的动作，

躺 however emphasises the movement of the body onto a flat surface,
这个平面可以是地面、床、沙发等。
said flat surface may be the ground, a bed, a sofa etc.
躺的方式可以是侧躺或仰躺，
The orientation of 躺 may be on ones side or on ones back,
强调的是身体的平放状态。
emphasising the usual orientation of the reclined body.

在某些情况下，
Under some circumstances,
卧和躺可以互换使用，
卧 and 躺 are mutually interchangeable,
但卧更常用于描述静态的休息状态，
but 卧 (is) more often used to describe the static state of rest,
而躺则可以包括休息、睡觉等多种状态。
whereas 躺 may include resting, sleeping etc. various states.

例如，
For example,
我们可以说“他卧在草地上休息”，
We might say "He is lying on the lawn resting."
这里强调的是他的身体平放并处于休息状态。
Here we emphasise his horizontal resting state.
而“她躺在床上翻阅书籍”，
whereas "She is lying on the bed flipping through a book."
则强调的是她身体平放，可能是在阅读或休息。
emphasises her body is horizontal, (but) possibly (she is) reading or resting.

总的来说，
In summary,
卧和躺都是描述身体平放的动作，
卧 and 躺 both describe movement of the body to a horizontal position,
但卧更偏向于静态的休息状态，
but 卧 tends to indicate a static state of rest,
躺则包含了卧的含义，
whereas 躺 includes the meaning of 卧,
同时也可以指其他平放身体的动作。
and, at the same time also refers to the act of moving ones body to a horizontal position.


卧一般是侧卧，
卧 generally means lie on ones side,
躺一般是平躺。
躺 generally means to lie flat on ones back.

卧 is more literary/ classical, common in idioms like 臥薪嘗膽，臥虎藏龍, 臥冰求鯉 and acts as an adjective element in some nouns, for example, 臥室，臥榻，臥墊
躺 is more colloquial/ contemporary, common in modern writing and speech. It is always a verb
躺卧 is a compound word for 'lie down'

Generally speaking, ‘卧’ is used in more formal literature context. It means laydown in general, and it can be “仰卧” - facing up，“侧卧” - facing side or “俯卧” - facing down or lay on your belly.
In comparation, ‘躺’ normally used in less formal/oral way, and is not suitable to be used for laying on one's belly. That normally will be translate to ‘趴’.
